# Error IM002 with isql but odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini exist

Tags: odbc, unixodbc, isql

I'm currently installing a virtuoso server on my Mac OS X.

However I got an error when I run the isql command:

```
isql -v 1111 dba dba
   [IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no defaul driver specified
   [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

However when I tried 'odbcinst -j':

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/francocy/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

And in each odbc.ini the driver is specified:

```
[virtuoso-odbc]
Driver = /usr/local/opt/virtuoso/lib/virtodbc.so
```

And in the odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
VOS = Virtuoso

[VOS]
Driver = virtuoso-odbc
Description = Virtuoso Open-Source Edition
Address = localhost:1111
```

I don't understand why I get this error. I searched on the dozen of similar topic but I did not find solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird. The problem was solved by re-installing virtuoso with homebrew and by unlinking isql from unixodbc package. It seems to have conflict regarding the isql package.